How to add Allow file uploads to Azure web app environment variables
I'm doing a PoC for an enterprise chatbot, and have set it up using Azure OpenAI deploy to app. All the UI stuff is fixed, Cosmos DB set up etc. But the last thing I want to add is the Upload files feature. But I cant really figure out what the variable name and/or value should be, in order to allow this in the front end. Anyone has the same issue that could help me out?
Tried adding
ALLOW_FILE_UPLOADS = true, 
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS=.pdf,.docx,.txt,.jpg,.png, 
FILE_UPLOADS=On, 
MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH=50, 
UPLOAD_DIR=wwwroot/uploads.

The file icon comes up quick when restarting the application, but quickly goes away, so it looks like somethings working

Please share the error logs.

There's no error logs, I just want to figure out if there's a specific Variable name, that would correlate to an upload files feature in Azure Web App. And then also what key should be attached for it to appear.

@user28512649 Your front end is partially detecting the upload capability but isn't fully supported by the back-end configuration. Add detailed logs to capture upload-related errors

@user28512649 Azure Portal > App Service > Diagnostics Settings > Enable Application Logs.

Environment variables depend on the framework or app's internal handling. Let’s make sure the variables are correctly configured for common frameworks.

Use ALLOW_FILE_UPLOADS, but ensure the code reads it.

import os

ALLOW_FILE_UPLOADS = os.getenv("ALLOW_FILE_UPLOADS", "false").lower() == "true"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS", "").split(",")
MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = int(os.getenv("MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH", 50)) * 1024 * 1024  # MB to bytes
UPLOAD_DIR = os.getenv("UPLOAD_DIR", "./uploads")

print(f"File Uploads Allowed: {ALLOW_FILE_UPLOADS}")
print(f"Allowed Extensions: {ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS}")
print(f"Max Content Length: {MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH} bytes")
print(f"Upload Directory: {UPLOAD_DIR}")

For Azure App Service, wwwroot/uploads might work, but test with ./uploads or a blob storage directory

Azure App Service uses read-only storage by default in the wwwroot folder.

Modify the chatbot's UI to include a file upload option.
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" />
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

Check the front-end sends the file to the back-end.
document.getElementById("uploadForm").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);

  const response = await fetch("https://your-app.azurewebsites.net/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  });

  const result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
});


Turn on app service logs:

Logs:
2024-11-28 10:15:23.456 INFO app: Received upload request for file 'malicious.exe'
2024-11-28 10:15:23.457 ERROR app: File extension '.exe' is not allowed.
2024-11-28 10:15:23.458 ERROR app: Upload failed for file 'malicious.exe' - Unsupported file type.
2024-11-28 10:20:00.567 INFO app: Received upload request for file 'example.pdf'
2024-11-28 10:20:00.568 ERROR app: Directory 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\uploads' does not exist.
2024-11-28 10:20:00.569 ERROR app: Upload failed for file 'example.pdf' - Internal Server Error.
2024-11-28 10:25:00.123 INFO app: Received upload request for file 'Img.png'
2024-11-28 10:25:00.124 INFO app: File size: 21 KB
2024-11-28 10:25:00.125 INFO app: File extension '.png' is allowed.
2024-11-28 10:25:00.126 INFO app: Uploading 'Img.png' to Azure Blob Storage container 'uploads'
2024-11-28 10:25:01.345 INFO app: File 'Img.png' successfully uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.

